# 'unexpected end of file' error while using if - then - else - fi statement in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

I am trying to read a file if file exist in a folder. But when I use if-then-else statement to check file exists or not, this error will occur.
syntax error: unexpected end of file

I wrote script in centos7. I have tried in many ways to fix this error such as, removing square brackets, adding spaces and removing semi-columns. Still i couldn't find any solution.

```
flag="0"
path="/home/abc/file.txt"
if [ -f $path ]; then
 flag="1"
 echo "file exists"
else
 echo "file could't find"
fi
```

I expect to print set flag as "1" if file exists and print "file could't find" if file doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you really have a newline character after the `fi`? Check with `od -cx yourscript`.

Comment: Does your script file have DOS/Windows-style line endings? See: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: @user1934428  - "0000560   d   '   t       f   i   n   d   "  \r  \n   f   i  \r  \n
           2764    2074    6966    646e    0d22    660a    0d69    000a
0000577" this is the final line when executing od -cx file.sh

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Thank you, It worked after running sed -i 's/\r$//' file.sh

Comment: Since `then\r` is not `then`, the parser reaches the end of the script while still waiting for the keyword `then`. It just assumed that `then\r`, `else\r`, and `fi\`r` were all additional commands for the condition.

Comment: By the way, this is the *first* thing the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) suggests you check before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs quite fine. Chances are you've some special characters. Install `dos2unix` using `yum install dos2unix` or any other way and then do `/usr/bin/dos2unix /path/your_script.sh`. Now run your script and see if it works.